# What is the proper way to build and reference an editable local Python module?

Tags: python, pip, python-module, pyproject.toml

I am trying to build a module that will be shared among more than one Python application in a project.

I have a folder with a `pyproject.toml` with the following content.

```ini
[project]
name = "data_audit_shared"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="Josh Russo", email="jrusso@example.com" },
]
description = "Shared code for data audit"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
```

When I try to reference `data_audit_shared` I get the message `No module named 'data_audit_shared'`.

My dependency in my project is `-e ../../data_audit_shared` and it installs properly.

This is what my venv `site-packages` looks like.

[image]

How do I update module or the reference to be able to use this module?

---

Edit - Tried removing `-e`

So when I remove `-e` I get the module listed in the installed modules. Is there something I am missing to be able to properly install and reference my module with `-e`?

---

Edit - Relative paths

I'm assuming that this is because I'm trying to reference a package outside of my project folder root. The strange part in my mind is that you can use this syntax with a Git repo. Why would it not behave similarly?

Comment: it shouldn't behave differently. I think you need to give us more details, include the precise commands you are using, inclination is to rule out that you are installing to the wrong virtual environment for some reason.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, I just tried to create an example and it worked. I will need to go back to my other project and see if I can identify what I am doing wrong.